# Are there standard short notations for ascending and descending cyclic permutations?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups, notation

In a paper I am currently writing I use **cyclic permutations** of the form
$$
(k,k+1,\dots,\ell)
$$
and
$$
(\ell,\ell-1,\dots,k)
$$
of *consecutive elements* quite a lot (I added the commas to avoid possible ambiguity with algebraic operations) and I would like to shorten this notation as much as possible.

To provide some context, I have an action of a colimit of symmetric groups on a certain tensor algebra which interacts with some other endomorphisms of the algebra and so I get rather lengthy expressions of operators, hence my desire to compress the notation further. Ideally, the notation will also be well amenable to light algebraic operations within the permutation (e.g. adding an integer or multiplication by an integer).

I am currently using the symbol $[a,b]$ as a placeholder to mean one or the other, depending on whether $a \geq b$ or $a \leq b$, but I would like to know if there is already an accepted or at least somewhat popular short notation for this before I go on inventing something obscure that could easily be confused with a few other things and then TeX it everywhere.
Thus my question:

> Is there a common or at least a somewhat popular short notation for ascending and descending cyclic permutations of consecutive integers?

Comment: Note that a similar notion, the _integer interval_, is sometimes written as $[a\mathbin{..}b]$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Integer_intervals) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056510/what-is-the-mathematical-symbol-for-range).

Comment: You could also do worse than imitating the [colon operator](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/colon-operator) common in many programming languages, for example, writing $(3:5)$ to mean $(3,4,5)$. That one, at least, is understood to return an ordered list rather than an unordered set. (EDIT: [In R](https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/05/16/colon-operator-in-R/), at least, this also works for descending sequences.) To answer your original question, though, I'm not aware of any common notation for what you want specifically.

Comment: Maybe worth defining TeX macros so that you can TeX it everywhere and then change the notation by changing one line.

Comment: $c_{a..b}$ is probably what I'd use.